# Why is interface inheritance allowed on a struct and why can a class not be inherited

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, reference

In C#, structs are value types, both interface and class are reference type. Then, why can struct not inherit a class but it can instead inherit an interface?

```
class a { }
public struct MyStruct : a //This will not be allowed.
{

}

interface a { }
public struct MyStruct : a  // and this will work
{

}
```

Comment: What source do you have that says that interfaces are reference types?

Comment: interface is Implemented not Inherited.

Comment: @Samuel: A storage location (variable, field, array slot, etc.) of interface type is guaranteed to hold either `null` or a reference to an object whose type implements that interface.

Comment: A struct type definition defines one `Type`, but two types (lowercase `t`): a storage-location type and a heap-object type.  An implicit conversion exists from the former to the latter, and an explicit conversion from the latter to the former.  The object type must inherit from `ValueType`, but because object types may implement interfaces in addition to inheriting from a base class, a struct may do so as well.  Storing a struct that implements an interface into a storage location of that interface type will convert the struct to its associated heap object type and store a reference to that.

Comment: Interface types are not always reference types, however: using an interface is used as a generic constraint does not imply that a type satisfying that constraint is a reference type.  Assume the existence of `class Foo<T> where T:IBoz {public T Value; ...}` and `struct Boz : IBoz {...}`.  In a `Foo<Boz>`, `Value` will hold a structure of type `Boz`; in a `Foo<IBoz>`, `Value` will hold a *reference* to a heap-object which implements `IBoz` [the object could be the heap-object form of `Boz`].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Interface` is not a reference or value type by itself. `Interface` is a *contract*, which reference or value type subscribe to.

You probably refer to a fact that `struct` that inherits from  `interface` is boxed. 
Yes. This is because in C# struct members are defined like `virtual` members. And for
virtual members you need to maintain virtual table, so you need a reference type.

Let's do following to prove this:

```
public interface IStruct {
     string Name {get;set;}
}

public struct Derived : IStruct {
     public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Now, let's call it in this way:

```
//somewhere in the code
public void ChangeName(IStruct structInterface) {
     structInterface.Name = "John Doe";
}

//and we call this function as 

IStruct inter = new Derived();
ChangeName(inter); 

//HERE NAME IS CHANGED !!
//inter.Name  == "John Doe";
```

This is not something we would expect from value type, but this is *exactly* as reference types work. So here what happens is that value typed instance of Derived is *boxed* to reference type constructed on top of `IStruct`.

There are performance implications and also misleading behavior, like in this case, of the value type that starts to behave like a reference type.

More on this subject can have a look on:

[C#: Structs and Interface](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/10/05/477238.aspx)

Comment: Be advised that if you declared using var / Derived (e.g. var inter = new Derived();) change name won't work, as the boxing is discarded (as explained in the Abhinaba Basu blog post...

Answer (score 0):

An Interface is not a value or a reference type.  In fact I believe that it is the only construct that does inherit from the Object base type in the .Net framework.

See [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx)